# Merge dataframes based on at least one column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

I have df1, which has badge.number.one and badge.number.two. I have d2, which has column badge.number.

I want to match all rows were either badge.number.one == badge.number or badge.number.two == badge.number, and I have some other columns to match on too.

I want to use left_join()

How do I do this?

Additionally, if I have multiple matches, how I do mark which rows in the new dataframe are multiples?

`by <- join_by(date, district, beat, is.female, black,
officer.badge.number == badge.number)

## note I did not incoporate the second badge here, but I want to

merged.temp <- dplyr::left_join(as.data.table(x),
as.data.table(y),
by,
na_matches = "never",
multiple = "any")`

Edited to provide sample data

This is what I would like it to look like. Note I am working with a much larger dataset:

```
df1 = data.frame("badge.one" = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                 "badge.two" = c("5", "6", "7", "8"),
                 "A" = c("lorem","ipsum", "et", "sed"))
                 


df2 = data.frame("badge" = c("1", "0", "6", "4"),
                 "B" = c("happy", "birthday", "to", "you"))


#what I want it to look like

> df.merge
  badge.one badge.two badge     A     B
1         1         5     1 lorem happy
2         2         6     0 ipsum  <NA>
3         3         7     6    et    to
4         4         8     4   sed  <NA>
```

Comment: Please provide the sample data. You can use `dput()` for this

Comment: How does the 3rd row match here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `left_join()` iteratively and then fill the NA entries from the successful join:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 = tibble("badge.one" = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
             "badge.two" = c("5", "6", "7", "8"),
             "A" = c("lorem","ipsum", "et", "sed"))

df2 = tibble("badge" = c("1", "0", "6", "4"),
             "B" = c("happy", "birthday", "to", "you"))

# add row indicator
df1 <- df1 |> mutate(row = row_number())
df2 <- df2 |> mutate(row = row_number())

df1 |> 
  left_join(df2, join_by(row, badge.one == badge)) |> 
  left_join(df2, join_by(row, badge.two == badge)) |> 
  mutate(B = coalesce(B.x, B.y), .keep = "unused")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   badge.one badge.two A       row B    
#>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr> <int> <chr>
#> 1 1         5         lorem     1 happy
#> 2 2         6         ipsum     2 <NA> 
#> 3 3         7         et        3 <NA> 
#> 4 4         8         sed       4 you
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, but this seems to have merged row 2, where neither badge 1 or badge 2 == badge

Comment: In row 2 of `df2` the value of `badge` is "0"

Comment: But it has a match in the data, you want to only search by row values i.e. only return the match if it exists in that row. I'm not sure how to do this but keyword like "rowwise join" or "merge by row values" may help

Comment: Have a look now, I added the row number as a merge key. But then the third row doesn't have match either, unlike in your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
df4 <- merge(df1,df2,by='row.names')

df4 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(B=ifelse(badge %in% c(badge.one,badge.two),B,NA))
```

It does not match the expected answer, but it seems you want to return NA if there is no match in a given row?